# Dependencies in the app to fulfil the API Target 26 in Aug/Nov 2018

Tags: android

Google announced that

> Google Play will require that new apps target at least Android 8.0 (API level 26) from August 1, 2018, and that app updates target Android 8.0 from November 1, 2018

Do the dependencies used in the app need to target at least Android 8.0 (API level 26)?

Comment: I disagree with this being marked as a duplicate. This question asks about dependencies whereas the other "duplicate" question and answers only make mention of the app itself (which in my opinion is very different than the dependencies).

Comment: According to the [announcement](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk#check_and_update_your_sdks_and_libraries), **YES**, "Make sure that your third-party SDK dependencies support API 26".

However, in regards to dependencies targeting API 26, is anywhere aware of how the Google Play Store could validate that? AFAIK, the targetSdkVersion value of your app is the only version that appears in the compiled apk. Also, there are really popular libraries like Facebook SDK that only target API 25. I'm really curious what other developers are doing as well.

Comment: @blinkmacalahan In my opinion, the [announcement](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk#check_and_update_your_sdks_and_libraries) means that the developers need to make sure the dependencies are compatible with API 26, but they are not required to be complied or targeted at API 26. Am I right?

And, I think that Google Play store *only* validates the API version in the app but not the dependencies used in the app.

Comment: Msg from google- Your app needs to be using runtime permissions for us to complete the review. Please update your app to target API level 26 or above and resubmit the declaration form. I am asking, do I need to update the TargetSDK of every dependency I am using or just the one which is contributing to my Android Manifest. There are certain dependencies in the merged Manifest which are under Manifest Sources and some are under Other Manifest File(not contributing any element to the main Manifest File).

Answer (score 0):

As Jake Wharton pointed out [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/8wxuci/questions_about_3rd_party_libraries_targeting_api/e1zkbx4/), if the targetSdkVersion is specified in the dependencies it is merged in the app using it. So it is best that the dependency does not have any targetSdkVersion in its gradle and leave it to the app using it. Otherwise, the merger would either use the higher targetSdk or fail.

Comment: Msg from google-

Your app needs to be using runtime permissions for us to complete the review. Please update your app to target API level 26 or above and resubmit the declaration form.

I am asking, do I need to update the TargetSDK of every dependency I am using or just the one which is contributing to my Android Manifest.

There are certain dependencies in the merged Manifest which are under Manifest Sources and some are under Other Manifest File(not contributing any element to the main Manifest File).

Comment: Jake Wharton was wrong, or maybe things have changed since then. [Manifest merging rules](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests) clearly state that "attributes in the `<uses-sdk>` element always use the value from the higher-priority manifest" and "build configurations from the `build.gradle` file override any corresponding attributes in the merged manifest file".