# How do you targetSdkVersion for third party libraries, and what happens if you don't?

Tags: android

From [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk) and [here](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk.html#check_and_update_your_sdks_and_libraries) Google says "Make sure that your third-party SDK dependencies support API 29".

However, Google doesn't say what happens if third-party libraries *don't* target API 29. For example, [greenDAO](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/build.gradle) targets API 25. It's not clear to me what happens if my app targets 29, but greenDAO targets 25 - is this resolved somehow?

I'm assuming that so long as my app targets API 29, it will continue to auto-update, because this is the current state of the world: Play store currently requires at least API 28, and my app auto-updates even with third party targets targeting less than API 28.

I found the following topics, but they weren't comprehensive.

[Dependencies in the app to fulfil the API Target 26 in Aug/Nov 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187530/dependencies-in-the-app-to-fulfil-the-api-target-26-in-aug-nov-2018?newreg=b9b3a55f7e3a49f9b09709b1b117ec58)

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/8wxuci/questions_about_3rd_party_libraries_targeting_api/

Comment: The accepted answer to the post you linked says: "the merger would either use the higher targetSdk or fail" so that seems to answer your question. Does your project compile? If not, this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56526194/using-multiple-library-with-different-sdk-version-in-android-studio

Comment: It doesn't say anything about libraries targeting API 29 - it says 'make sure they **support** API 29'.